# TemplateSyntaxError at /posts/post

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to make the form display the value of the average rating for each post.

Here is my template

```
  <a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted" href="{% url 'posts:post_detail' post.id %}">
    <h2>{{ post.school_name }}</h2>
    <p>Average rating: {{ post_ratings.get(post=post).avg_rating }}</p>
    <p>Автор: {{ post.author }}</p>
    <p>Опубликовано: {{ post.created_at }}</p>
    <p>Обновлено: {{ post.updated_at }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'posts:post_edit' post.id %}">Редактировать</a>
    <a href="{% url 'posts:post_delete' post.id %}">Удалить</a>
  </a>
```

my view

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    post_ratings = Comment.objects.values('post').annotate(avg_rating=Avg('score'))
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'post_ratings': post_ratings
    }
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', context)
```

my models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='KZ')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    content = models.TextField()
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    your_email = models.EmailField(default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(1)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.post.id)])
```

Why am I getting this error?

I tried to change the lines in the tamplates

```
<p>Average rating: {{ post_ratings.get(post=post.id).avg_rating }}</p>
```

Comment: Do such computations and run queries in the view. Then pass computed values via context along with those values you already passing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this kind of pythonic logic directly in the templates. In example you cannot use brackets inside `{{ }}` and `{% %}`. You can change this part:

```html
<p>Average rating: {{ post_ratings.get(post=post.id).avg_rating }}</p>
```

To that

```html
<p>Average rating: {{ post.get_avg_rating }}</p>
```

If you add proper function to your `Post` model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    # fields

    def get_avg_rating(self):
        # count and return the result you need for post
```

Comment: I had in my head that it was a flask template and not django. I'm shocked to find that you apparently can't have logic in the template rendering, but I'm not familiar with the setup on django

Comment: You can some basic logic, like `{% for x in xyz %}`, but just not everything you'd like. I don't think that you can do everything in Flask's templates also.

Comment: You can't do _everything_ in `jinja2` but you can definitely have logic e.g. `value="{{ product.actual_bin_size }}" {% if not has_dept_access %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %}` is just pulled from my current editor

Comment: @roganjosh You can also do that logic in Django. I believe it's almost the same - Django's Template engine and jinja2. But you cannot use parenthesis, can you?

Comment: Then it's incorrect to say "you cannot use pythonic logic directly in a template" when it's exactly what you're doing

Comment: @roganjosh you are right, I've edited the answer a bit.